# Pass parameters and execute scripts in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to make a service like this :

```
datastax:
  image: luketillman/datastax-enterprise:5.1.0
  ports:
    - "9042:9042"
  volumes:
    - /datasets:/tmp/scripts
  command: [ "-s",
             "bash -c \"sleep 40 &&
                        cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/init.cql\""]
```

Starts Cassandra in search mode (`-s`) and then (when it's up), execute `init.cql` via `cqlsh`.

Is it possible to do with compose ? How to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a command having multiple sub-commands like this:

```
datastax:
  image: luketillman/datastax-enterprise:5.1.0
  ports:
    - "9042:9042"
  volumes:
    - /datasets:/tmp/scripts
  command: bash -c "dse cassandra -s; sleep 40; cqlsh -f /tmp/scripts/init.cql"
```

Note that you must use the full `dse cassandra -s` command, you can't reuse the default command from the images AFAIK.